# How to join multiple tables of same dataset in QuickSight

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I can join one table with other in QuickSight of one dataset. But if one table is related with two or three tables of the same dataset, is there any way in QuickSight to do that? I can only apply left/right/inner/outer join within two tables in QS of same dataset?

I can do that through direct query but is there any way to do that when I am connecting with RDS?

I am getting something in the following URL, but it is not clear is that is the only way to relate multiple tables of same dataset or not through graphics interface and without direct query. Can anyone help?

I am expecting something like

select a,b from table1,

d,e from table2,

f,g from table3

from table1

left join table2 on (a=d)

left join table3 on (a=f and e=g)

Comment: _"I am getting something in the following URL"_ - what url?